# Postgres logical & with bigint

Tags: sql, postgresql

My select SQL is

```
select id & b'00000000ffffffff'
```

I need to put mask on id, id is bigint.

Actually the id should be divided on two integers up & down parts.

Comment: How about `/` and `%` ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the high and low parts, simply use

```
SELECT id >> 32 AS high, id & 4294967295 AS low
```

If you insist in having the number in hex, you can write `x'FFFFFFFF'::bigint` instead of 4294967295.

Comment: its ok, may you suggest how to do it over & operation ?

Comment: please over HEX mask ))

Comment: Ok, if you really want - but it makes no difference.